# Why is AngularJS form not updating validity until clicking into another field and changing value?

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-forms

Good morning! I am still fairly new to AngularJS and did not find an answer that I could fully comprehend.

There is a form structured like this:

- Name
- Email
- **Color** [Option Red, Option Blue]

  - **REQUIRED Field that only appears if Option Blue is chosen for 'Color'**

When selecting **Option Blue**, the second set of fields appear. However, when **unselecting** 'Option Blue', the required fields are again hidden, but the form still 'sees' that the field is empty until I click into another field (like 'Name') and type another value.

A condition checks the boolean **$form.$valid** every time the event listeners (?) fire off, which is onItemSelect and onItemDeselect and onSelectionChange.

From what I understand of Angular, I... *think* that another digest(?) cycle has not started (?) until I click **and** type into another field? Sorry for all of the question marks - my knowledge is a little flakey and I can't quite paste the source code for reasons.

Is my understanding correct? And if so, are there any recommended ways to resolve this issue?

**Edit:** I have added some example code below with dummy variable and object names, plus some pseudo code to summarize larger sections of code.

```
<script>
   var app = angular.module('myApp',[some stuff]);
   app.controller('myContropper', function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
         [some variables for scope]
         $scope.color = {};
         $scope.optionB = {
               hue: null;
               saturation: null;
         };
         [some other variables that only have values of OptionB is chosen and subsequent fields are populated]

         $scope.colorChange = function() {
              if color is changed, clear all associated arrays and values by setting it to either '[];' or 'null;'
         };

         $scope.checkForm = function() {
              if OptionB is not chosen, clear all options related to OptionB

              use $scope.form.$valid boolean value and do something with it
         };

         function onItemSelect(item) {
              if OptionB is selected, set the flag for that option to true
              $scope.checkForm();
         }
         function onItemDeselect(item) {
              if OptionB is not selected, set the flag for that option to false
              $scope.checkForm();
         }
   }
</script>
```

I had set up some debugging alerts. I notice that when I unselect OptionBlue, the alert will have the following line:
    requiredFieldifOptionBisChosen: object Object

However, upon clicking on another field and typing any value, the form will refresh (?) the validity, and it'll say:
    requiredFieldifOptionBisChosen: null

Comment: could you provide an example code.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco Sure! Allow me several minutes to turn it all into some... sort of psesudo code-ish example :)